# How to implement distance queries in CakePHP?

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a query (from Google Maps) like so:

```
SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(MY_LAT) ) * cos( radians( LATITUDE ) ) * 
cos( radians( LONGITUDE ) - radians(MY_LONG) ) + sin( radians(MY_LAT) ) * sin( radians( 
LATITUDE ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM zips
ORDER BY distance
```

I would rather this be a custom find in Cakephp, so how do I do that?

MY_LAT and MY_LONG are params passed in.
LATITUDE and LONGITUDE are columns in zips table.

Comment: Make it a virtual field then just select that field from your find query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a behavior like the geocoder behavior ( https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Model/Behavior/GeocoderBehavior.php#L208 ) and attach it to your model with

```
$this->Model->Behaviors->attach('Tools.Geocoder');
```

and call

```
$this->Model->setDistanceAsVirtualField($lat, $lng, $fieldName);
```

this way a virtual field is attached and will retrieve and contain your distance value just like any other normal field. you can also sort/filter by that field then.